# Azure Web App env variable hand over to pipeline

Tags: docker, variables, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have defined in Azure Web App Configuration / Application Settings a ENV variable.
[image]

My question is how, I could hand over to my Azure Pipeline this value, and build it to my image.

I tried many options like:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Display environment variables'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-ChildItem env: | Sort-Object Name
```

But here didn't listed my AAA_TEST variable.

Also with this:

```
env:
    TEST: $(AAA_TEST)
```

Is there any option to get the connection between this env variable and my pipeline?

Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Azure Pipelines variables and App Service variables are completely different systems that aren't integrated together. You shouldn't be storing application configuration in your pipeline, and you shouldn't be storing pipeline configuration in your app service.

Comment: Hi Daniel. 
We have TenantID and ClientID which is stored in App Service Env Variable. 
We want to integrate, these ID's in the Azure Pipeline to build into Frontend to make API requests.
Any idea to have a solution for this?
Thx

Answer (score 0):

I believe azure keyvault will satisfy your requirement.
Place the required values in azure keyvault secrets or keys. Then refer the  keyvault values in app services in azure and library in ADO as one time configuration.
So whenever you change values in keyvault, the same will be reflect in both azure app service and ADO.
I have followed below steps to meet the requirement.
Below is the key in my app service.
[image]
Now I place the testvaule01 in key vault and refer in app settings as below.
[image]

Next, click on the secret, current version and copy the link.

[image]

Now replace the value in app service and click on save.

[image]

In ADO, navigate to library in pipelines, create a new variable group, enable link secrets from an Azure keyvault then select right subsciption and key vault and add variables as below.
[image]

Now you can add that library in CI/CD pipeline and use as an environment variables as shown below.
[image]

```
variables:
- group: var-grp-az-key-linked

steps:

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Display environment variables'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      Get-ChildItem env: | Sort-Object Name
  env:
    TESTKEY01: $(testkey01)
```

Save and Run the pipeline to verify the env variable.

[image]

**Note: As testkey01 is created as a secret in azure keyvault it appears as masked value.**

Resources will automatically start using new values whenever changes happened in secrets.